# Data on BroadcastReceiver is null

Tags: android, android-intent, broadcastreceiver

I am trying to send data through a Intent to my broadcast before being recorded by AndroidManifest. When I click on my notification to trigger the broadcast I get null in the method `OnReceive(Context context, Intent intent)`

```
Intent intentOnclick = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SYNC, null, context, NotificationButton.class);
PendingIntent onClickPending = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, intentOnclick, 0);

notificationView = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.download_notification);
intentOnclick.putExtra("test", notificationView);
intentOnclick.putExtra("test1", 1);

builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context)
    .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
    .setAutoCancel(true)
    .setContent(notificationView);

notificationView.setProgressBar(R.id.download_progress, 100, 0, true);
notificationView.setTextColor(R.id.title_notification, Color.BLACK);
notificationView.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.play_or_pause_btn, onClickPending);
```

My BroadcastReceiver:

```
 @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        RemoteViews remoteViews = intent.getParcelableExtra("test");
        int test = intent.getIntExtra("test1", 265);
        // return null twice object
}
```

Comment: I see you are using putExtra after providing the `intentOnClick` to `onClickPending`. Try to do that before.

Comment: null anyway @Shaishav

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must put the extras in the `Intent` **before** you make the call to `PendingIntent.getBroadcast()`, otherwise they will not be in the `Intent` that actually gets delivered.